# Exit node security from Man-in-the-middle attacks

Tags: security, exit-relays

Apparently, any exit relay may steal some private data from `HTTP` requests (like auth data / cookies / credit card information), if the connection itself is not encrypted.

Does `HTTPS` provide a reliable protection against this? AFAIK `HTTPS` is vulnerable to Man-In-The-Middle attacks. Is there either a way to ensure that any particular exit node does not perform this kind of attacks or a reliable mechanics that prevents exit relays from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a certificate checks for your HTTPs like [Perspectives Project](http://perspectives-project.org)

Comment: Will this help if the hacker has his own valid certificate and uses it while he's tampering with my connection?

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser no it won't help him : you'll be able to know that the site is using another certificate

Comment: Well, seems legit. Hope SSL expiration is not causing a vulnerability in `Perspectives`. I will probably drill into this deeper, but later... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Tor Project also does exit scanning to find exit relays who do man in the middle attacks. [Exitmap](https://github.com/NullHypothesis/exitmap) is such a scanner. You can also download and run it. If you or another person finds such bad relays, please [report them to Tor](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/ReportingBadRelays) so that they can be banned from the network.